# Convert script in Jquery function when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate a button function in jquery, I am a learner of jquery but i am not sure how scripting can be converted into jquery

Here is a code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _hmc = _hmc || [];
_hmc.push(['app', '<application ID>']);
_hmc.push(['title','Talk with us.']);
(function() {
var hm = document.createElement('script'); hm.type = 'text/javascript';
hm.async = true;
hm.src = 'https://hipmob.s3.amazonaws.com/hipmobchat.min.js';
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; b.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, b);
})();
</script>
```

I need to place it inside button click

```
 jQuery('.live-chat').click(function()
   {

   });
```

Also if anyone would like to elaborate how things work e.g  what is  || [] etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you would need to do what you want is the following:

```
jQuery('.live-chat').click(function() {
    var _hmc = _hmc || [];
    _hmc.push(['app', '<application ID>']);
    _hmc.push(['title','Talk with us.']);

    var hm = document.createElement('script');
    hm.type = 'text/javascript';
    hm.async = true;
    hm.src = 'https://hipmob.s3.amazonaws.com/hipmobchat.min.js';
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, b);

    return false;
});
```

As for your questions:

1. `||` means OR in javascript
2. `[]` is shorthand for creating a new array, or an 'array literal'
3. This means the line `var _hmc = _hmc || [];` means `_hmc` equals `_hmc` OR a new array